# Validation Pattern MUMPS

Tags: intersystems-cache, mumps

I am working to create a program in M that reads an input of names in a certain format. Once the user places a null value it prints out all of the values. Where I am getting stuck is reading into a global variable. I look forward to any input I can receive.

```
          n prompt,val,done
          s prompt="Enter a name (LAST,FIRST MI): "
          s val="" f in=1:1 s val=$O(^ZNAME(val)) q:val=""
          f  w !,prompt r val q:val=""  d   q:done 
          . i val'?1.A1",".1" "1.A.1(1" "1A) w !,"Invalid name" q
          . s val=$GET(^ZNAME)
          . s done=1
          i val="" q  
          w !,"You entered: ",val
         . s done=1
         q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you want to do but this is what I built:

- read names till you give an empty name
- if the name follows a pattern add him to ^ZNAME
- at the end print all names in ^ZNAME

Here you go:

```
readlist
    N prompt,val
    S prompt="Enter a name (LAST,FIRST MI): "
    F  W !,prompt R val Q:val=""  D
    .   I val'?1.A1",".1" "1.A.1(1" "1A) W !,"Invalid name"
    .   E  S ^ZNAME(val)=""
    F  S val=$O(^ZNAME(val)) Q:val=""  D
    .   W !,"You entered: ",val
    Q
```

Example (using GTM):

```
GTM>D readlist^ZZTEST

Enter a name (LAST,FIRST MI): first,last
Enter a name (LAST,FIRST MI): name,surname
Enter a name (LAST,FIRST MI):
You entered: first,last
You entered: name,surname
GTM>zwr ^ZNAME
^ZNAME("first,last")=""
^ZNAME("name,surname")=""
```

Comment: I basically bought a book on M programming and as I go through a chapter I try to combine everything I've learned and make practice problems for myself. Thank you DAimor and user3532194. A few examples I saw on the internet actually had the $Order as one of the first lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks strange. In first this line `s val="" f in=1:1 s val=$O(^ZNAME(val)) q:val=""` is useless, just order all values in first subscript of global. Then your code should fail with `UNDEFINED` error for done variable when entered val will passed your pattern. And finally it gets new value from global `^ZNAME`, and does not matter what was entered, it will get one value for all times.